# How to determine interface RUNNING state without ifconfig?

Tags: bash, scripting, wifi, ifconfig

Some background: sometimes my wi-fi connection suddenly goes down so I type `sudo ifconfig wlan0` and check for the word `RUNNING`. The corresponding line looks like:

```
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  [...]
```

When the connection goes down there's no `RUNNING` setting; I can't connect to anything but the interface is still up.

I'm thinking of writing a script to periodically check for the `RUNNING` state. To extract that string, using `awk` would be something like: `sudo ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/RUNNING/ {print $3}'`.

Is there another way such as checking the filesystem instead of parsing ifconfig's output?

I'm using Debian Wheezy.

Thanks.

---

**More information:**

OK, just did some research and cleared up some conceptual confusion.

The `UP` and `RUNNING` flags are different. The first means the interface "is currently initialized" [1], i.e. "the system allocated the resources for the interface" [2]--it doesn't say anything about packet transmission.

The `RUNNING` flag actually indicates that packets are being sent and received. Apparently this flag disappears if e.g. the ethernet cable is unplugged.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/ipconfig-141/index.html

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679514/what-is-the-difference-between-iff-up-and-iff-running

I don't know what is going on with my (or any) wireless connection, but the result is the same: the interface remains up (the wi-fi led light remains on in my laptop) while the connection is completely lost.

Comment: Did you try to check in `/proc/net/*` ? BTW: to run `ifconfig` you do not need to be root, you should find it in `/sbin/`. In `/proc/net/dev` you can read the packages received and sent... the error... If you do not receive it is down...

Comment: Does the contents of `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate` change from `up` to `down`?

Comment: Hello @Hastur. Yes, i skimmed through /proc/net/ but found nothing relatively explicit about RUNNING. Actually, i don't know how or where ifconfig looks for that setting...

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, hello. I don't know yet because the connection has been stable so far. Will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Try `tree  /sys/class/net/wlan0` too...and search...

Comment: Could it be `/sys/class/net/wlan0/dormant`? So far (I think):
UP -> `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate`
MTU -> `/sys/class/net/wlan0/mtu`

Comment: @undostres If `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate` doesn't do the right thing, there's always `/sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier`.

Comment: Can you not just do `ip link show dev wlan0`?

Comment: @mikeserv, actually I could but that's not my original idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using commands like `ifconfig -s` or `netstat -i` one can check the following files to monitor a wi-fi connection status:

`/sys/class/net/wlan0/flags` indicates wheter the device is on or off. It tells nothing about packet transmission so it's not really useful to check if your connection is working or not. It's contents/values are `0x1003` (on) and `0x1002` (off).

`/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate` indicates if the connection is operational (packets are being sent and received). This file is equivalent to the `RUNNING` flag displayed by `ifconfig`. It's values are `up` and `down`.

`/sys/class/net/wlan0/carrier` works just like `/sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate`. It's values are `1` (up) and `0` (down). The file is empty if the device is turned off.